# Why can't I run Redhawk HelloWorld from python?

Tags: python, redhawksdr

I have Redhawk 1.9 loaded on a 32-bit CentOS 5 virtual machine.  I am trying to run the Redhawk HelloWorld component described here: http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch3.html.  I am able to launch and start the component in the eclipse sandbox.  I cannot run it from Python though.  I get the following error.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb 27 2012, 16:40:29) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ossie.utils import sb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/utils/sb/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from domainless import *
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/utils/sb/domainless.py", line 102, in <module> 
    from omniORB import CORBA, any
ImportError: No module named omniORB
>>>
```

Any ideas why it will not work?

Comment: at a guess you need the omniOrb python module ...

Comment: My bet is that the Eclipse sandbox mucks about with your PYTHONPATH either at the shell or by manipulating `sys.path`.  I'd try digging around the Redhawk docs and source, or just probing things like `sys.path` and `sys.modules` while in the sandbox to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably have to set your `PYTHONPATH` manually to include the appropriate directory. It looks like Eclipse is doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your example as root. If you can successfully run as root, then you have a permission problem on your directories or files. How do you identify the files that have the incorrect permission ? I ran the following command,
     strace -o test.out python -c "from ossie.utils import sb"

This command will write the output to test.out. Look for the string "denied", which will identify the file that has the incorrect file permission.